# Duplicate MySQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP() result on successive calls

Tags: mysql

Why does this code return the same `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` value for each call?

```
DECLARE myStamp1 FLOAT;

DECLARE myStamp2 FLOAT; 

DECLARE n INT;

SET myStamp1 = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();

SELECT SLEEP(1) INTO n;

SET myStamp2 = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();

SELECT myStamp1, myStamp2;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `FLOAT` datatype only has 23-bits for the mantissa, which is essentially equivalent to seven decimal digits of precision.  (Yes, technically, the limit is more accurately specified as six digits.) But the point is that a `FLOAT` represents no more than seven decimal digits of precision.

And right now, `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function is returning an integer value of ten decimal digits.  So, a one second change is going to change only the 10th (lowest order) decimal digit (or rollover a 9 to a 0).  But that isn't enough difference to result in a different FLOAT value. (Eventually, the value of the FLOAT will change, but any one second difference is very unlikely to result in a different `FLOAT` value.)

I recommend you try using `BIGINT`, `DECIMAL(10,0)` or `TIMESTAMP` datatype, or use a `DOUBLE` if you need(?) the scalability of a floating point type.

---

### Excerpted from the MySQL Documentation

`<snip>`

Functions that return the current date or time each are evaluated only once per query at the start of query execution. This means that multiple references to a function such as NOW() within a single query always produce the same result. (For our purposes, a single query also includes a call to a stored program (stored routine, trigger, or event) and all subprograms called by that program.) This principle also applies to CURDATE(), CURTIME(), UTC_DATE(), UTC_TIME(), UTC_TIMESTAMP(), and to any of their synonyms.

`</snip>`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

(The code you show must be in a stored program, since the `DECLARE` statement is valid only within a stored program.)

Comment: OK, it's a documented infelicity then. Except that I have an example of the same thing happening when calling an SP that only calls UNIXTIME_STAMP() once. And then I call that SP again minutes later -- it produces that same value yet again.  So, it's almost as if it calcs that call not at every invokation of the SP, but at compilation.

Comment: @user1905164: the FLOAT datatype has precision of (at most) 7 decimal digits, and UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is going to be returning 10 decimal digits. (answer updated)